# How can I produce word embeddings from code-mixed data using Facebook MUSE?

Tags: natural-language, word-embeddings, fasttext

I am doing sarcasm detection using code mixed data. Sentences are in English and Hindi written in English alphabets. Is there a way to apply Facebook MUSE to generate word embeddings out of this data?